# How do you evaluate this function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Given the function $g(x) = x^2 + 2x$, evaluate:

> $\displaystyle\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}$, where $x\ne a$

This is how far I got:

$\displaystyle\frac{x^2 + 2x - a ^ 2 - 2a}{x-a}$, where $x\ne a$

Comment: is it $$g(x)=x^2+2x$$?

Comment: Where is your attempt? If you have not attempted, why should we?

Comment: Sorry about that, yes it is. I have changed it now and thx for pointing out the mistake :)

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @jame_smith it is pretty straightforward

Comment: @jame_smith, try to write $g(a)$ as you did with $g(x)$.

Comment: Your replaced $g(x)$ with what it means. Why didn't you replace $g(a)$ with what it means?

Comment: Last hint - $x^2+2x-a^2-2a=(x^2-a^2)+2(x-a)$. Can you continue?

Comment: It should be $x^2+2x-a^2\color{red}{-}2a$ instead of $x^2+2x-a^2\color{red}{+}2a$.

Comment: I got close x + a - 2.

Comment: @jame_smith, it should be $x+a\color{red}{+}2$ instead of $x+a\color{red}{-}2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:
$$g(x) - \color{red}{g(a)} = x^2 +2x - \color{red}{(a^2+2a)} = x^2+2x-\color{red}{a^2-2a}=x^2-\color{red}{a^2}+2x-\color{red}{2a}=(x-a)(x+a)+2(x-a)$$
Now devide by $(x-a)$ you will get:
$$\dfrac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}=x+a+2$$

Comment: I understand as to why you have to factor them together. But in future problems, how do I know if I should factor something or not?

Comment: You factor because you have $x-a$ in the denominator to cancel it

Comment: does that mean if I have more than one term in the denominator I factor them?

Comment: @jame_smith: sometimes it's very useful to factorize the functions you have in order to simplifiy them

Comment: So would you factorize, If there is more than one term in the denominator ?

Comment: @Jame_smith: we **factorize if it is possible** to simplify the function, think of the rational function: $\dfrac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}$ as it is why do not simplify to get simple expression!